# Why do I get deadlock when setting a future in a subscription callback? (Only with MultiThreadedExecutor) (rclpy)

Tags: ros, ros2, rclpy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a node that publishes message, and another node (constructed with an unset future) that sets the result of the future to the incoming message in its subscription callback. I then add both of these nodes to an executor (in the same process) and spin until the future is complete.

If I am using a `MultiThreadedExecutor` then the future gets set, but it gets stuck during a `spin` and the program never exits. If I am using a `SingleThreadedExecutor` then this does not happen, and the program successfully exits.

My Publisher Node looks like this:

```
pubnode = Node('pubnode_' + str(os.getpid()))

pub1 = pubnode.create_publisher(String, 'topic1', latching_qos)
msg1 = String()
msg1.data = "hello1"
pubnode.get_logger().info("Publishing hello1")
pub1.publish(msg1)
```

My Subscription Node looks like this:

```
future_msgs = Future()

subnode = Node('subnode_' + str(os.getpid()))
subnode.create_subscription(String, 'topic1', lambda msg : ([
        subnode.get_logger().info("Received message on topic1"),
        future_msgs.set_result(msg)
]), latching_qos)
```

And I start the Nodes like this:

```
exe = MultiThreadedExecutor() if args.exe == 'M' else SingleThreadedExecutor()
print("Using {}".format(str(type(exe))))
exe.add_node(pubnode)
exe.add_node(subnode)

future_msgs.add_done_callback(lambda fut : print("Future is done"))
exe.spin_until_future_complete(future_msgs)

print("Goodbye!")
```

I have also tried:

```
while future_msgs.done() is False:
    print('------ Begin Spin')
    exe.spin_once()
    print('------ End Spin')
```

But I have the same issue. The `------ Begin Spin` and `Received message on topic1` are printed but during the second cycle a `'------ Begin Spin` message is printed without a following `------ End Spin`, so it must be stuck inside `spin_once()`.

The full code can be found [here](https://github.com/craigh92/ros2deadlock_ws/blob/master/src/my_package/my_package/my_node.py), with instructions on how to run it [here](https://github.com/craigh92/ros2deadlock_ws).

Why does this happen? Or is this a bug in ros? I will submit an issue if this is a problem with ros, and not just how I am using it.  If that is the case, where should I submit the bug report?

Thanks.

**Edit:**

I have submitted a bug report [here](https://github.com/ros2/rclpy/issues/585)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/355325/why-do-i-get-deadlock-when-setting-a-future-in-a-subscription-callback?-(only-with-multithreadedexecutor)-(rclpy)/) by [CraigH92](https://answers.ros.org/users/54432/craigh92/) on ROS Answers with karma: 128 on 2020-06-19

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looks like this was identified as a bug and already resolved in the mainline development in [rclpy#585](https://github.com/ros2/rclpy/issues/585), which is the OP reported. Nice community-driven dev cycle!

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2023-02-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0